# Github Action- Annonations doesn't get displayed for some EsLint errors on pull request

Tags: typescript, next.js, eslint, github-actions

I have created a **GitHub Action** that runs EsLint on pull requests and displays errors as annotations. I have used this [EsLint action](https://github.com/iCrawl/action-eslint).
Though, it doesn't display annotations for some files under `/src` folder but it displays the errors in [logs](https://github.com/aysp-99/RocketMeet-client/pull/24/checks) under `checks` tab.
Here's the file for EsLint GitHub Action: `./github/workflows/linter.yml`

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  eslint:
    name: eslint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: install node v12
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - name: yarn install
        run: yarn install
      - name: eslint
        uses: icrawl/action-eslint@v1
        with:
          custom-glob: "**/*.{ts,tsx}"
```

I am not able to figure out why isn't it working as I have set the appropriate `glob pattern` as `custom-glob`. Here's the link for the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/RocketMeet/RocketMeet-client) to refer the file structure.